# When would you use PendingIntent?

Tags: android

I am trying to understand from the API the purpose of `PendingIntent`.

Sometimes some methods I use requires this, I still did not get the idea right.

Can anyone could explain? why can't i just use context?

Thanks,

moshik

Answer (score 22, accepted):

A `PendingIntent` is a combination of a gross action (start an activity? start a service? send a broadcast?), the action details (in the form of an `Intent`), and a `Context`. The `PendingIntent` is handed to the operating system, which will perform the gross action on the `Intent` at some future point (hence, "pending"). The `Context` is for security -- Android will execute the `PendingIntent` with only the permissions of the `Context`, so a `PendingIntent` cannot access things that the `Context` requesting it cannot.

Comment: So if iam getting it right, i would use Pending Intent on regular Intent on cases when i wanna make sure  i am accessing things that the context can access?

Comment: You use a `PendingIntent` when you need one for a method parameter.

Comment: A real-world example would be very helpful.

Comment: A real-world example is the AlarmManager class. Its API only allows you to schedule PendingIntents instead of regular Intents.

Comment: @CommonsWare . Is pending intent is only meant for external application eg. notification ?

Comment: @RohitSingh: Yes. I cannot think of a place where you would use it purely within an app. There is nothing *stopping* you from using it within an app, but it is not necessary.

Answer (score 4):

A Pending Intent is a token that you give to another application like Notification Manager which allows this other application to use the permissions of your application to execute a predefined piece of code.

Some activity triggers after some time or invokes by some specific event for that pending intent is used.
And generally pending intent is stored in a process queue.

Normal intent is used at that particular time, but pending intent is used as predefined time.

e.g. Alarm manager which is called at specific time.